# Collapsed panel with loader

Tags: javascript, extjs

I configured the following loader on a panel 'dashboard-panel' and everything works well as usual,
PHP Code:

```
 loader: {                
     url: '...',                
     loadOnRender: true,               
     renderer: 'component',
}
```

But when I set the panel collapsed (`collapsed:true`), the following error occurs:

[image: Error]

Comment: What is your ExtJS version? There is a bug regarding `collapsed:true` in certain versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `collapsed:true` in Ext JS 4.1. Upgrading to Version 6.2 solved the problem!